# Python: Calling decorator inside a function

Tags: python

Trying to understand decorator. So, is it possible to call decorator inside a function, either by defining the function inline or independently ?

```
def deco(f):
    print "In deco"
    def wrp(*args, **kwargs):
        print "In wrp"
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrp

@deco
def f1():
    print "In f1"

def f2():
    print "In f2"

def f3():
    print "In f3"
    # Calling independent function
    # Error : Invalid syntax error
    @deco
    f2()
    '''
    @deco
        f2()
    Error : IndentationError: unexpected indent
    '''
    print "End f3"

def f4():
    print "In f4"
    # Making function inline
    @deco
    def f5():
        print "In f5"
    '''
    Error : NameError: global name 'deco' is not defined
    '''
    print "End f4"
```

Also, explanation for error in f4() will be helpful.

Comment: There is no error in `f4`...

Comment: Syntax is right, but if we try calling the function f4() then it is throwing the mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, the error only comes when run in ipython shell and not in python shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. The `@` is simply syntactic sugar for wrapping a function in another one: so `@deco` before the definition of `f1` is exactly the same as `f1 = deco(f1)` afterwards.

So it simply doesn't make sense to "use" a decorator inside another function. If you really wanted to, you could do this:

```
deco(f2)()
```

ie, create the wrapper and then call it, but I have no idea why you would want to do that.

Comment: There is a validation logic of a class instance in a decorator, but now there is a list of class instance which has to be validated. I was thinking of using the already written validation logic on the list. So, stuck with the syntax for that. Thanks `f1 =  deco(f1)` explained everything.